# getting a ComplianceException

Tags: java, exception, ejb, weblogic, build-process

when trying to run weblogic.appc on my app I get the following error:

"In EJB CallerEJB, the throws clause for method hasBalance(java.lang.String) in the bean class contains exceptions that are NOT in the throws clause of the corresponding remote interface method."

This is the method in my remote interface:

```
public boolean hasBalance(String sin) throws RemoteException, NamingException,     CreateException, XrefAccountNumberException, AccountNotFoundException, AccountBadFormatException, ExclusiveLockException, ValidationException;
```

This is the method in the bean class:

```
public boolean hasBalance(String sin) throws RemoteException, NamingException, CreateException, XrefAccountNumberException, AccountNotFoundException, AccountBadFormatException, ExclusiveLockException, ValidationException{
...
}
```

I don't understand why weblogic thinks they have different exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I never bothered to check what I was importing when I pressed ctrl + shift + O
one exception had the same name but different source